Which App Description is Used in the SharePoint App Store: package-solution.json or Submission Input?
I'm developing a SharePoint app using SPFx and am preparing to publish it for the first time in the app store. I've added the app description in the package-solution.json file as instructed. However, during the submission process, I'm prompted to enter the description again. My question is: which app description will be used in the app store—the one in package-solution.json or the one I enter during submission?
I'm asking this because I've encountered an issue with the package-solution.json file: the description does not support HTML tags. There's an open issue on GitHub regarding this.
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9522
When I manually deploy the app in the app catalog, the description appears as plain text. However, in the app store, it is showing in a rich text control.


When publishing a SharePoint app, the description that appears in the SharePoint App Store is the one you enter during the submission process, not the one in the package-solution.json file.
The package-solution.json file is used for internal configuration and deployment, while the submission input is what users will see in the store.
